# number of active sessions increasing in oracle 10g

Tags: java, jsp, jdbc, oracle10g

I have made a jsp page on which in have run sql queries.Every time i refresh the page a new active session is being created due to which after the maximum actives session reaches the database connectivity is lost and the following error is displayed:

java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12519, TNS:no appropriate service handler found

How to stop this increase in session.

jsp page:

```
   <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ page import="dao.Dao" %>
<%@ page import="model.Chat_model" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
<%@ page import="model.Register_model" %>
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
     <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
      <body>
     <table>
     <%

     Dao object=new Dao();

      ArrayList<Chat_model> a=new ArrayList<Chat_model>();

      String email1=(String)session.getAttribute("email1");
      a=object.selectChat(email1, ((Register_model)(session.getAttribute("user"))).getEmail());

     String name1=(String)session.getAttribute("name1");
     String email2=((Register_model)(session.getAttribute("user"))).getEmail();
     String name2=((Register_model)(session.getAttribute("user"))).getName();
     for(Chat_model k:a)
     {
if(email1.equals(k.getEmail1()))
{
    out.println("<tr><td><b><u>"+name1+"</u>:</b></td><td>"+k.getChat()+"</td> </tr>");
}
else
{
    out.println("<tr><td><b><u>"+name2+"</u>:</b></td><td>"+k.getChat()+"</td><tr>");
}
    }









       %>


       </table>

         <form action="../Controller" method="post">
         <textarea name="chatbox" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
           <input type="hidden" name="action" value="chatsend"></input>
           <input type="submit" value="Send"></input>



           </form>
            </body>
            </html>
```

database transaction method:

```
          public ArrayList<Chat_model> selectChat(String s1,String s2)
  {
    DatabaseConnection db=new DatabaseConnection();
    Connection conn=db.getConnection1();
    Statement stmt = null;


    String email1 = null;
    String chat=null;

    ArrayList<Chat_model> a=new ArrayList<Chat_model>();
    try
    {
        stmt = conn.createStatement();


        String sql = "SELECT email1,chat FROM chat_all where email1="+"'"+s1+"' AND email2="+"'"+s2+"' OR email1="+"'"+s2+"' AND email2="+"'"+s1+"' order by tm_stamp";
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

        while(rs.next()){

            Chat_model object=new Chat_model();


             email1=rs.getString("email1");
             chat=rs.getString("chat");
             object.setEmail1(email1);
             object.setChat(chat);

             a.add(object);



          }


    }

    catch(Exception e)
    {
    e.getStackTrace();  
    }

      return a;
}
```

database connection class:

```
        public class DatabaseConnection {

String driver = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@siddhartha-PC:1521:xe";
String username = "system";
String password = "password";

Connection conn = null;
public Connection getConnection1(){

    try {
        Class.forName(driver);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return conn;
}

public boolean closeConnection(Connection conn){

    try {
        conn.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return true;
   }
       }
```

Comment: First of all dont connect to database from JSP

Comment: actually i am calling methods in jsp page that interact with database

Comment: Can you post you jsp file by editing your question? Have you properly closing your db session after fetching data? Try like this, while every time calling your db connection methods first check db session is null. Then do the connectivity. Hope i made you some sense.

Comment: I can't see any code that actually calls `closeConnection()`. Additionally: you should be using a proper `DataSource` with connection pooling instead. If you open a phyiscal connection each time your jsp is displayed you are going to kill the server.

Comment: As @SashiKant suggested, but taking it farther, JSPs are not the place to put code.  You shouldn't be connecting to DBs from a JSP, nor should you be calling code that then interacts with a DB from a JSP.  You should have a "Controller" layer that does all your backend processing (services, DBs, etc) and sends the UI (the JSP) only the stuff it needs to display.  The reason we moved to this design pattern is because it's near impossible to debug what happens in the JSP code.  Scriptlets are EVIL!  Avoid like the plague.